# Add SQL row to a ASP label based on a condition

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

SQL Table:

```
ID  CreatedDate     MessageText     CreatedBy   IsActive    ClientText      LocationText    ProviderText    SpecialtyText
1   March 4, 2015   dsdfsdf         Test1       False               
2   March 4, 2015   dsdfsdf         Test2       True                
3   March 4, 2015   dsdfsdf         Test2       True        Test Client     location1       Test2           MD
4   March 4, 2015   This is to add  Test1       False       Test Client     location2       Test3           DD
```

Getting the table:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(gloString))
{
    string strSql = @"SELECT * FROM [DB].[dbo].[table2]";
    try
    {
        // create data adapter
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(strSql, conn);
        // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable

        myDataSet = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(myDataSet);
    }
    catch (Exception ce)
    {
    }
}
```

I have the following label in my ASP.net page: `<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" Font-Size="x-small" runat="server" Text="" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>`

How can I update the label like this:

```
lblMessage.Text += "<b>ALL MESSAGES:</b> <br />";
foreach (ROW WHERE COLUMN {CLIENTTEXT}, {LOCATIONTEXT}, {PROVIDERTEXT}, AND {SPECIALTYTEXT} IS EMPTY)
{
    lblMessage.Text += {CREATEDDATE} + " - " + {MESSAGETEXT} + "<br /><br />";
}
lblMessage.Text += "<hr />";
lblMessage.Text += "<b>SPECIFIC MESSAGES:</b> <br />";

foreach (ROW WHERE COLUMN {CLIENTTEXT}, {LOCATIONTEXT}, {PROVIDERTEXT}, OR {SPECIALTYTEXT} IS NOT EMPTY)
{
    lblMessage.Text += {CREATEDDATE} + " - " + {MESSAGETEXT} + "<br /><br />";
}
```

Comment: switch to mvc mate, there you can use the data inside the view. works so much better, trust me!

Comment: The project is 90% done so it will be even more work to switch but thank you for the heads up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I get it, you want to update your label using the rows that dont contain a "SpecialityText". The problem is you dont know how.

Let's say the DataSet you use in your page is still named *myDataSet* after you fetch it, the following code should do the trick. Please note I assumed you have some data access namespace imported. *DBNull.Value* should be replaced with whathever the null representation your helper uses.

```
string specific = "";
string generic = "";

foreach (DataRow r in myDataSet.tables[0].Rows){
    //Add all your conditions here. It seems you want two groups of messages
    if (r["SpecialtyText"].ToString == ""){
        generic += r["CreatedDate"] + " - " + r["MessageText"]  + "<br /><br />";
    }
    else{
        specific += r["CreatedDate"] + " - " + r["MessageText"] + "<br /><br />";
    }
}

lblMessage.Text = generic + "<hr /><b>SPECIFIC MESSAGES:</b> <br />" + specific;
```

Comment: Is the above code if it is empty? I have to check for multiple columns. So I can just use AND/OR statement in the if statement, right? Thanks.

Comment: This is good except I get an error in the `equals`. `Assembly or reference missing?`

Comment: You can indeed check as many columns as you want, although the LINQ @Aghmed Daou suggested might be more appropriate. I updated my answer though in order to remove the need for iterating twice. Also try to check using == against DBNull.Value. I'm a VB programmer, and error indeed slipped in my code.

Comment: I converted the code so it corrected it for me. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: `if (r["SpecialtyText"].ToString() == "")` <- updated code which made it work correctly. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a difference for the 2 for loops you showed.

If it's just one table you should be using a DataTable instead of a DataSet

You can do it like this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)//table is a DataTable
{
    var clientText = row["ClientText"].ToString();
    var locationText = row["LocationText"].ToString();
    var providerText = row["ProviderText"].ToString();
    var specialtyText = row["SpecialtyText"].ToString();
    var createdDate = row["CreatedDate"].ToString();
    var messageText = row["MessageText"].ToString();

    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientText) && 
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(locationText) && 
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(providerText) && 
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(specialtyText))
    {
        lblMessage.Text += createdDate + " - " + messageText + "<br /><br />";
    }
}
```

then add else block if you need. You can also use linQ

```
foreach (var clientText in from DataRow row in table.Rows
                           let clientText = row["ClientText"].ToString()
                           let locationText = row["LocationText"].ToString()
                           let providerText = row["ProviderText"].ToString()
                           let specialtyText = row["SpecialtyText"].ToString()
                           where string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientText) && 
                                 string.IsNullOrEmpty(locationText) && 
                                 string.IsNullOrEmpty(providerText) && 
                                 string.IsNullOrEmpty(specialtyText)
                           select clientText)
{
    //some code here
}
```

Comment: The first loop is if all the specified columns are empty and the second loop is if any of the specific column is not empty.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge so you should be able to adapt my answer, I gave you 2 options

Comment: I am currently using DataSet. I have to convert it to DataTable first.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge you don't have 2 you can do access the first table of the set `myDataSet.tables[0].Rows` instead of `table.Rows`, It was an attempt to tell you that a datable is more appropriate if you have only one table

Comment: For the second option, how to add the specific column to the `lblMessage` label? Thanks.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge same way as version 1, `let` creates variables

Comment: I added the following to replace `insert code here`: `lblMessage.Text += clientText + "<br />";` and it is blank. It just adds the break statement.

Comment: You have to negate the expression `!string.IsNullOrEmpty` for each add `!`